# Kivy clear Builder to unload Widgets

Tags: python, kivy

I have a App with two screens the loginscreen and the secret screen.
The login screen is generated by a kv file and is loaded automaticly.

If login data is submitted my app decrypt connected.py and import it.

my connected.py looks like:

```
    secret_kv = '''
    <Connected>:
        RelativeLayout:
                id: layout

    class Connected(Screen):

        Builder.load_string(secret_kv)
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Connected, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def disconnect(self):
        self.manager.transition = SlideTransition(direction="right")
        self.manager.current = 'login'
        self.manager.get_screen('login').resetForm()
        self.manager.remove_widget(self.manager.get_screen('connected'))
        del sys.modules["connected"]

    def remove(self):
        print self.remove_widget('raised_button')
```

Now my problem:

It works fine but every login fired a `Builder.load_string(secret_kv)` and so the layout from secret screen get one more and is overlayed to the others!

Is it possible to clear the `Builder.load_string()` by fireing `disconnect(self)` something `like Builder.**unload**_string()`?

I have try to unload the module with del `sys.modules["connected"]` but Kivy keep all the secret screen containing widgets!

It would by nice if there are a tricky python or kivy way to clear with logout `disconnect(self)` all Objects and datas.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution for working with multiple kv an py files!

```
from lang import Builder
Builder.load_file('filename.kv')
Builder.unload_file('filename.kv')
```

or `main_widget.clear_widgets()`